# Can we use Generative Adversarial Network for Neural Machine Translation?

Tags: nlp, machine-translation, generative-adversarial-network

I'm going to implement a translator based on NMT(Neural Machine Translation). In here I hope to use only monolingual corpora without using parallel corpus data for my dataset. Is it possible to train the model using only monolingual corpora data? I'm grateful if someone can share your idea regarding this.

Comment: https://paperswithcode.com/task/unsupervised-machine-translation
At this link , you'll find a list of papers with different approaches to "unsupervised" neural MT, i.e. using monolingual data only

Comment: thank you for your kind response. It was really helpful for me to get an idea regarding my implementation.